# SQL Search refresh by row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to using select scripts to extract the weekday column from a table in the database. And dividing "MWF" into "Monday", "Wednesday" and "Friday". Each day need to display in an individual row.

What I have here is :

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEETING_DAY, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL, 'i'), FROM_TIME_HHIIAP  as DAY 
FROM
    (SELECT
        CASE WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'F')THEN ('Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'FS')THEN ('Friday,Saturday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'M')THEN ('Monday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MF')THEN ('Monday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MT')THEN ('Monday,Tuesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MTH')THEN ('Monday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MTTH')THEN ('Monday,Tuesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MTW')THEN ('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MTWTH')THEN ('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MTWTHF')THEN ('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MW')THEN ('Monday,Wednesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MWF')THEN ('Monday,Wednesday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'MWTH')THEN ('Monday,Wednesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'S')THEN ('Saturday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'T')THEN ('Tuesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'TH')THEN ('Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'THF')THEN ('Thursday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'TTH')THEN ('Tuesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'TTHF') THEN  ('Tuesday,Thursday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'TW')THEN ('Tuesday,Wednesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'TWTH')THEN ('Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'W')THEN ('Wednesday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'WF')THEN ('Wednesday,Friday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'WTH')THEN ('Wednesday,Thursday')
             WHEN (DAY_MEET.MEETING_DAYS = 'WTHF')THEN ('Wednesday,Thursday,Friday')
             ELSE ('Unknown')
         END MEETING_DAY, 
         DAY_MEET.*
     FROM 
         UTDBA.IS_167_DAY12_MEETING_INFO DAY_MEET)

CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  
           LENGTH(MEETING_DAY) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(MEETING_DAY, ',', ''))+1;
```

But seems like the LEVEL stays at the last character after the first row, so the result is wrong. Anyone knows how to refresh Level back to the first word for each row?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which I'm guessing is Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You can do this with a `join`:

```
select mi.*, d.name
from (select mi.*,
             replace(mi.meeting_days, 'TH', 'X') as meeting_days_x -- do something about Thursday
      from UTDBA.IS_167_DAY12_MEETING_INFO mi
     ) mi join
     (select 'M' as abbrev, 'Monday' as name from dual union all
      select 'T' as abbrev, 'Tuesday' as name from dual union all
      select 'W' as abbrev, 'Wednesday' as name from dual union all
      select 'X' as abbrev, 'Thursday' as name from dual union all
      select 'F' as abbrev, 'Friday' as name from dual union all
      select 'S' as abbrev, 'Saturday' as name from dual
     ) d
     on mi.meeting_days_x like '%' || d.abbrev || '%';
```

Comment: Thanks man， I tried this on the Oracle Developer, but it shows error: ORA-00904: "MI"."MEETING_DAY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 22

Comment: @Shaw . . . That was a typo.  Your column name is in the plural.